# How to use @PreAuthorize with IDs in a collection?

Tags: spring-security

I have a service method with the parameter is a collection of item id as below:

```
List<Item> getItems(Collection<Long> itemIds)
```

How can I use @PreAuthorize to secure it?

Or should I only use @PostFilter? I'd like to do the checking before the method is executed :)

Comment: If `@PreAuthorize` can accomplish this purpose, I think it will be more semantically matching.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is `@PreFilter`:

```java
@PreFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'com.example.Item', 'read')")
List<Item> getItems(Collection<Long> itemIds)
```

Note that item ids that the user has not permission to will be silently dropped.

Comment: It throws 'org.springframework.security.acls.domain.IdentityUnavailableException' with message 'Could not extract identity from object 1'

Comment: @RichardMZ Are you sure you are calling `hasPermission` with 3 parameters? That method should not throw that exception.

Comment: Sorry. What I said is the exception and message show in the HttpResponse. The exception in the console is 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.getId()'. And I did calling `hasPermission` with 3 parameters :)

Comment: @RichardMZ Probably need the entire stack trace to resolve that.